# Using SSIS OR T-SQL Split a column of quoted & unquoted comma separated values into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parsing, ssis

I have comma separated data in a column named C0.
The data in C0 looks like this:

| C0 |
| --- |
| "Pacey LLC.",213830ZZ,11/1/2017,11/1/2017,"297,311.74","2,371.40",0.00,"1,325.18",0.00,42.22,"123,986.56" |
| Mike The Miker,9814140VCD,12/1/2018,12/1/2018,"3,917,751.99","419,743.54","36,642.66","344,090.43",0.00,10.00,"2,434,671.06" |

And I want it to end up like this:

| F1 | F1 | F3 | F4 | F5 | F6 | F7 | F8 | F9 | F10 | F11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Pacey LLC." | 213830ZZ | 11/1/2017 | 11/1/2017 | 297,311.74 | 2,371.40 | 0.00 | 1,325.18 | 0.00 | 42.22 | 123,986.56 |
| Mike The Miker | 9814140VCD | 12/1/2018 | 12/1/2018 | 3,917,751.99 | 419,743.54 | 36,642.66 | 344,090.43 | 0.00 | 10.00 | 2,434,671.06 |

I've tried nested replaces, but couldn't find a pattern to reliably search without regex which is T/SQL? I've also tried a [TOKEN approach in SSIS by this feller](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/ssis-how-to-split-a-single-string-into-multiple-columns-using-derived-column), but neither fruitful.

The nested replace approaches got stuck on the money fields that are under 1,000 (like 0.00) and the SSIS TOKEN approach presumes all fields are quote delimited, which in my example they aren't.

Comment: This type of thing is exceedingly difficult in TSQL. You may find that an SQLCLR function utilizing Regex is your best bet. Moral of the story: don't store multiple pieces of info in the same column

Comment: You can't reliably use regexes on CSV data. CSV is a streaming protocol and is properly implemented with a state machine. I agree with @Charlieface that you should write a parser for this in SQL CLR, but don't try to regex it, use [RFC 4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were told already, TSQL is the wrong tool for this. Nevertheless this can be done (at least for the set given). If this is a one-time action you might give it a try. If this is a re-occurring task in a real-life scenario I'd try to get the data in an appropriate format.

However, this would work for the given lines:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourString NVARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES(N'"Pacey LLC.",213830ZZ,11/1/2017,11/1/2017,"297,311.74","2,371.40",0.00,"1,325.18",0.00,42.22,"123,986.56"')
                     ,(N'Mike The Miker,9814140VCD,12/1/2018,12/1/2018,"3,917,751.99","419,743.54","36,642.66","344,090.43",0.00,10.00,"2,434,671.06"');
```

--Your data includes dates in a culture specific format (something really! bad)
--Better switch to ISO8601
--Setting the date format will help, but is NOT recommended

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
```

--the first cte will use `APPLY` together with a computed `TOP()`
--This will allow to get each single character, one by one.

```
WITH singleChars AS
(                    
SELECT t.ID
      ,A.Pos
      ,SUBSTRING(t.YourString,A.POs,1) AS CharOnPos
FROM @t1 t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP (LEN(t.YourString)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values) A(Pos) --master..spt_values can be any table with sufficient rows
)
```

--we continue with a *recursive cte*
--it will run through the string and find if we are *within* a quoted area or not

```
,recCTE AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CASE WHEN CharOnPos='"' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS QuoteIsOpen
          ,CAST(CharOnPos AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS GrowingString
    FROM singleChars WHERE Pos=1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sc.ID,sc.Pos,sc.CharOnPos
          ,A.QuoteIsStillOpen
          ,CONCAT(GrowingString,CASE WHEN sc.CharOnPos=N',' AND A.QuoteIsStillOpen=0 THEN N'$%&' ELSE sc.CharOnPos END)
    FROM singleChars sc
    INNER JOIN recCTE r ON sc.ID = r.ID AND sc.Pos=r.Pos+1 
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CASE WHEN sc.CharOnPos='"' THEN CASE WHEN r.QuoteIsOpen=1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ELSE r.QuoteIsOpen END )) A(QuoteIsStillOpen)
)
```

--this CTE performs a trick with `TOP 1 WITH TIES` together with `ORDER BY` a partitioned `ROW_NUMBER()`
--The result will include the final string of the recursion by ID

```
,newlySeparated AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * FROM recCTE
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Pos DESC)
)
```

--The final `SELECT` uses a trick to split strings position- and type-safe

```
SELECT A.*
FROM newlySeparated ns
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'[["',REPLACE(REPLACE(ns.GrowingString,'"',''),'$%&','","'),N'"]]'))
WITH(Company    NVARCHAR(100)        '$[0]'
    ,Code1      NVARCHAR(100)        '$[1]'
    ,Date1      DATE                 '$[2]'
    ,Date2      DATE                 '$[3]'
    ,Decimal1   NVARCHAR(100)        '$[4]' --Using a numbers type might work here, this depends on your machine
    ,Decimal2   NVARCHAR(100)        '$[5]'
    ,Decimal3   NVARCHAR(100)        '$[6]'
    ,Decimal4   NVARCHAR(100)        '$[7]'
    ,Decimal5   NVARCHAR(100)        '$[8]'
    ,Decimal6   NVARCHAR(100)        '$[9]'
    ,Decimal7   NVARCHAR(100)        '$[10]') A
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

The result

```
+----------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+------+-------+--------------+
| Pacey LLC.     | 213830ZZ   | 2017-01-11 | 2017-01-11 | 297,311.74   | 2,371.40   | 0.00      | 1,325.18   | 0.00 | 42.22 | 123,986.56   |
+----------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+------+-------+--------------+
| Mike The Miker | 9814140VCD | 2018-01-12 | 2018-01-12 | 3,917,751.99 | 419,743.54 | 36,642.66 | 344,090.43 | 0.00 | 10.00 | 2,434,671.06 |
+----------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+------+-------+--------------+
```

Comment: What is the danger of using culture specific dates? And thank you.

Comment: @MikeG culture specific data (even wors with *language specific* data) depends on the cutlure setting on the executing machine. The same code with the same input might break on another server.  There are cultures, where `11/1/2017` is the first of November. A date like `31/1/2017` would create an error (which is actually better), while this date would just run by with a false result. Same with `1-Dec-2017`, which would break on a German server as it was "Dez" there. Same with numbers, as `10.123` can be more than 10k or just 10 with some decimals. See what I mean?

Comment: @MikeG Actually I do not know, if my result is correct... I took your date as 11th of January and 12th of January. Thinking about this again, I assume you wanted the first of Nov and Dec actually ??? That is exactly why... :-)

Comment: @MikeG Try the above with `dmy` and with `mdy` after `SET DATEFORMAT`.

Comment: This worked out for me before these changes since I was dealing w the dates further downstream.